# How to use the NOT IN operator (<>) in a GROUP_CONCAT with dates?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have the **calendar** table with all the dates of the month of December 2021 (I will only exemplify some dates within the table, but it is understood that it actually contains all the days of said month):

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-12-01 |
| 02 | 2021-12-02 |
| 03 | 2021-12-03 |
| 04 | 2021-12-04 |
| 05 | 2021-12-05 |

I have the **users** table:

| ID | name | num_employee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Andrew | 101 |
| 02 | Mary | 102 |

I have the table **assistances**

| ID | date | num_employee |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 2021-12-03 | 101 |
| 02 | 2021-12-04 | 101 |
| 03 | 2021-12-03 | 102 |
| 04 | 2021-12-04 | 102 |
| 05 | 2021-12-05 | 101 |
| 06 | 2021-12-06 | 102 |

I worked on a query to display the employee number, their name, the days they attended and the days they were absent:

```
SELECT u.num_employee,
       u.name,
       a.date AS attendances,
       c.date as faults FROM users u
JOIN (SELECT num_employee,
      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)) AS date FROM attendances
      WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
      GROUP BY num_employee) a ON a.not_employee = u.num_employee
LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)) AS date FROM calendar
           WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31') c ON c.date <> a.date
```

With the above query, I get this:

| num_employee | name | assists | faults |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Andrew | 3,4,5 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10... |
| 102 | Mary | 3,4,6 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10... |

In the attendance column I obtain the days of the month of December in which each employee had attendance, and in the faults I should only obtain the days in which there were absences, but all the days of the month of December are displayed.

I am almost sure that the problem is in how I evaluate that the numbers of the days displayed in the **attends** column are not displayed in the **absences** column. Specifically in this part I consider that my evaluation is wrong:

```
ON c.date <> a.date
```

I'm under the impression that since I'm working with `GROUP_CONCAT`, I should evaluate dates differently. How could I adapt my query to get the following?

| not_employee | name | attendances | faults |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Andrew | 3,4,5 | 1,2,3,6,7,8,9,10... |
| 102 | Mary | 3,4,6 | 1,2,5,7,8,9,10... |

The query in question cannot be adapted to use CTE given the version of MariaDB I am using. I am working on phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is a subselect.

This works also in mysql 5, with mysql 8 you could make a CTE from attendense.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE calendar (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `date` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO calendar
>   (`ID`, `date`)
> VALUES
>   ('01', '2021-12-01'),
>   ('02', '2021-12-02'),
>   ('03', '2021-12-03'),
>   ('04', '2021-12-04'),
>   ('05', '2021-12-05'),
>   ('06', '2021-12-06'),
>   ('07', '2021-12-07'),
>   ('08', '2021-12-08'),
>   ('09', '2021-12-09'),
>   ('10', '2021-12-10'),
>   ('11', '2021-12-11');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE users (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(6),
>   `num_employee` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO users
>   (`ID`, `name`, `num_employee`)
> VALUES
>   ('01', 'Andrew', '101'),
>   ('02', 'Mary', '102');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE attendances (
>   `ID` INTEGER,
>   `date` VARCHAR(10),
>   `num_employee` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO attendances
>   (`ID`, `date`, `num_employee`)
> VALUES
>   ('01', '2021-12-03', '101'),
>   ('02', '2021-12-04', '101'),
>   ('03', '2021-12-03', '102'),
>   ('04', '2021-12-04', '102'),
>   ('05', '2021-12-05', '101'),
>   ('06', '2021-12-06', '102');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT u.num_employee,
>        u.name,
>        a.date AS attendances,
>         (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)) AS date FROM calendar
>            WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
>            AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(EXTRACT(DAY FROM date),a.date)) as faults FROM users u
> JOIN (SELECT num_employee,
>       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM date)) AS date FROM attendances
>       WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
>       GROUP BY num_employee) a ON a.num_employee = u.num_employee
> ```

> ```
> num_employee | name   | attendances | faults           
> -----------: | :----- | :---------- | :----------------
>          101 | Andrew | 3,4,5       | 1,2,6,7,8,9,10,11
>          102 | Mary   | 3,4,6       | 1,2,5,7,8,9,10,11
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5d50a4c9eeac2ea1e622ea8fd4029615)*

Answer (score 0):

Consider a cross join of the users and calendar tables for all possible pairwise matches of employees and dates. Then left join to assistance and run aggregate `GROUP_CONCAT` with one conditional expression for *faults*:

```sql
SELECT u.num_employee,
       u.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT EXTRACT(DAY FROM a.date)) AS attendances,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT 
           IF(a.date IS NULL, EXTRACT(DAY FROM c.date), NULL)
       ) AS faults 
FROM calendar c
INNER JOIN users u
  ON c.date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
LEFT JOIN attendances a
   ON c.date = a.date
   AND u.num_employee = a.num_employee
   AND a.date BETWEEN '2021-12-01' AND '2021-12-31'
GROUP BY u.num_employee,
         u.name;
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=5ecffa53d429265122b0c5cd92249e44)</kbd>

Comment: you have seen that his version is too old?

Comment: Thanks, @nbk...I should read to last sentence of posts! I moved CTE to subquery.

Comment: Actually @nbk and OP, you do not need any subquery! `CROSS JOIN...WHERE` can be turned into `INNER JOIN...ON`.